# Can I selectively disable zsh completions?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, prezto

I'm using prezto with `zsh`, and find it a little slow to launch a new shell. (N.B. I'm attempting to optimise on a fast-ish system, before moving my configuration to other, slower systems.)

Benchmarking with `time zsh -i -c exit`:

- 0.046: `bash`.
- 0.080: `zsh` without prezto.
- 0.092: `zsh` with prezto, but no modules loaded.
- 0.138: `zsh` with prezto, and all "default" modules loaded, except for `completion`.
- 0.308: `zsh` with prezto, and all "default" modules loaded.

Firstly, `zsh` is 74% slower than `bash` to load. I could accept the further 73% slowdown (with prezto and all modules except completion loaded), but the 285% slowdown (with all modules) is a bit too much.

Some of these completions are useful, so **is there a way to selectively disable some of these?** I've heard mention of this [elsewhere](https://tlvince.com/fixing-slow-zsh-command-completion), although I'm not sure if this is only to improve tab-completion speed, or shell loading as well. (If I could selectively disable completion, this would allow me to profile and work out what was causing the slowdowns.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that prezto is loading the module from `/usr/lib/prezto/modules/completion`. With everything enabled, I deleted the contents of `/usr/lib/prezto/modules/completion/init.zsh`, which gave me the second quickest load time again. I then started systematically deleting lines in this file, and could isolate a single line causing the slowdowns.

```
unsetopt CASE_GLOB
```

N.B. in my specific case, the slowdown was caused by a duplicate `compinit` in my `~/.zshrc`. Presumably prezto was also running `compinit` with case off, resulting in a two-fold increase in load time.